# Formatting PHP code in Microsoft Expressions Web 4

Tags: php, expression-web

Does **Microsoft Expressions Web 4** has a option (or keyboard shortcut) to format PHP Code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this yourself? Of course you could be talking about formatting other people's code. In the former case, learning a good formatting pattern is a very good way to decrease the likelihood of bugs, as well as making your code more maintainable in the future.

Comment: What do you mean "format PHP".  You mean indenting and syntax coloring?

Comment: @alecwhardy I meant "Indenting". Actually Expression Web Has a option "Reformat HTML" which works only with HTML.

Comment: usually you have to do this yourself.  PHP is a freely typed language so whitespace (indents) makes no difference; therefore the programs do not force this whitespace.

Comment: unless the software is automatically coloring php code, detecting errors, etc. then it is most likely not going to indent for you

Comment: I would recommend using NetBeans, PDT, Notepad ++, or another editor for PHP and using Expression Web only for the HTML and CSS.  It is generally better to keep the HTML and the PHP sepereted.

Comment: @alecwhardy It is automatically coloring the PHP code but does not have a option to "Format" the code. Anyway Thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> this is the usual formatting for Visual Studio Codes for ASP.NET and C# codes.  I assume Microsoft would make the feature's keyboard shortcut the same. If it does not work then probably there is no built in.

Comment: Also tried Ctrl+K+D that does not seems working too... Means 'probably there is no built in.'

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the code you want to indent and hit the `tab` key. It will indent all selected lines. If you want to reduce the indent press `shift+tab`.

It won't magically fix poorly formatted code, but it will help you quickly indent large blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it's related to MS Expressions but you can do the same from this tool: http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDE to edit/format php code. The IDE has everything you may need to edit/format/deploy/refactor code. 
With PHPStorm you can reformat the code by using CTRL+ALT+L.

Answer (score 0):

try this to format the code of an existing page:

Open the web page you want to reformat.
In the Code pane, **right-click** and select **Reformat HTML**.